# Jquery autocomplete - select not called when hitting enter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My jquery autocomplete works nicely, the only issue I have is that I have to click the options in order for them to call my "select".

Since I can navigate with arrow keys in the list, I want to trigger select (or any function) when I press enter on a specific option. Is that possible?

```
$("#basicAutoComplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: encodeURI(search_url + request.term),
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.slice(0,10));
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText)
                        response([]);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 4,
            delay: 100,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                //dostuff

                return false;
            },
            search: function(e,ui){
                $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.bindings = $();
            }
        });
```

Comment: which autocomplete plugin do you use?

Comment: @cloned Jquery-ui, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: this seems to be due to `select` callback that you are specifying, default functionality is to replace the text in textbox with selected text but since you are specifying the call back explicitly, this seems to be overriding the default behavior. try removing select and then check

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider but I need select since that is where I execute my code, if I reamove it nothing will happen when I press an option.

The text does get set in the textbox like you are saying, but I also open a window and some other things when you select an option.

Comment: ok in select callback you can first put the selected value in textbox explicitly, and then execute your code for opening other Window

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider not really sure what you mean, if you can show an example please post an answer :)

Comment: can you please create a demo of your code using code pen? i will try updating an posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following piece of code, option is being selected upon hitting 'Enter' as well as code is being executed in `select` callback.

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tbox" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {alert(event.target.value);}

    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<Input type="text" id="tbox" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Ur snippet works but I cant see where its different from mine.

Comment: For some reason my select gets called when I press TAB :S

Comment: i think you can apply a simple if else inside select call back or page load using `onkeyup` event for textbox (need to confirm) to check if tab is pressed, then do what's intended.

Comment: didnt solve my issue but seems to be something else